# What's the most elegant way to bubble-sort in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, bubble-sort

Can this be cleaned up?

```
using System;  
class AscendingBubbleSort 
{     
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0,j = 0,t = 0;
        int []c=new int[20];
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Value p[{0}]:", i);
            c[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // Sorting: Bubble Sort
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<20;j++)
            {
                if(c[i]>c[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("c[{0}]={1}, c[{2}]={3}", i, c[i], j, c[j]);
                    t=c[i];
                    c[i]=c[j];
                    c[j]=t;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("bubble sorted array:");
        // sorted array output
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("c[{0}]={1}", i, c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant and Bubble Sort do not belong in the same sentence, IMHO.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, I would make the code as ugly as possible and litter it with comments like "deliberately adding yuckiness to code as a reflection of my distaste for this algorithm"... the teacher will respect you for your principles.

Comment: That's not bubble sort...

Comment: I have just voted to close as no-one has needed to write a bubble-sort for years.  (No longer relevant)

Comment: Oh yeah, after looking at your code again... the others are right; this isn't bubble sort. Get rid of the inner loop using `j`, put the loop with `i` inside a `while (numSwaps > 0)` block and set a new variable `int numSwaps = 0` that increments whenever you perform a swap and resets prior to the beginning of each `for` loop.

Comment: @Ian: There's value in learning how to translate an algorithm description into code though...

Comment: If you don't like Bubble sort's strategy of only comparing adjacent items, try using comb sort instead.

Comment: @Ian: I think the fact that most discussions of sorting place mention bubble sort suggests it is quite relevant, if only towards a discussion of sorting.  The fact that it's not generally appropriate in a commercial environment does not imply it is not worthy of discussion.

Comment: Re: my last comment -- sorry, you should definitely *not* initialize `numSwaps` to 0, as then the sort would never happen. You could just initialize it to 1, or use a `bool` as Jon Skeet suggests. Also, @Ian, to add to Jon's comment, I don't think we should underestimate the value of studying inefficient algorithms in order to better understand how to design *efficient* ones.

Comment: @Sinan - Agreed, but bear with me :) I want to use Jon Skeet's (excellent) answer to prove a point at work.

Comment: I would add that it's worth discussing bubble sort because it's the kind of naive implementation of sorting that somebody might come up with if they've never seen another sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you've pasted there isn't a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It's a sort of "brute force" sort but it's not bubble sort. Here's an example of a generic bubble sort. It uses an arbitrary comparer, but lets you omit it in which case the default comparer is used for the relevant type. It will sort any (non-readonly) implementation of `IList<T>`, which includes arrays. Read the above link (to Wikipedia) to get more of an idea of how bubble sort is meant to work. Note how on each loop we go through from start to finish, but only compare each item with its neighbour. It's still an O(n<sup>2</sup>) sort algorithm, but in many cases it will be quicker than the version you've given.

```
public void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    BubbleSort<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default);
}

public void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    bool stillGoing = true;
    while (stillGoing)
    {
        stillGoing = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i++)
        {
            T x = list[i];
            T y = list[i + 1];
            if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
            {
                list[i] = y;
                list[i + 1] = x;
                stillGoing = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ian: Not everyone who comes here is working on homework. With this answer, they'll find what they're looking for and can move on to the next problem. :)

Comment: I am (seriously) confused why you think this is a 'more real' bubble sort than the original. Both are bubbling, with different optimizations. Your version neglects to shrink the range.

Comment: @Henk: Take a look at the wikipedia article. Does the algorithm described there look anything like the original? In particular, the OP's code compares arbitrary pairs, immediately going against the "comparing each pair of adjacent items" part of the description of the algorithm. It's certainly a brute force swapping sort, but it's not a bubble sort.

Comment: Jon, you're right, i misread the `if(c[i]>c[j])` part. I've seen similar loops doing `if(c[j]>c[j+1])` and that's bubbling.

Answer (score 13):

The most elegant way to sort in C# is

```
Array.Sort( object[] )
```

That will work everywhere except in homework problems where the teacher asked you to implement the non-elegant bubble sort algorithm.
;-)

Answer (score 8):

Overall, there's nothing wrong with your bubble sort implementation. If I were doing a real code review, I'd make the following changes:

**Choose more descriptive variable names**

Why is your array just called `c`?

**Minimize variable scope**

All of your variables are declared at the top of the function. Unless this is a homework requirement or a coding standard, its more idiomatic to declare variables "close" to the location where they are used, preferably so they have the smallest amount of scope possible.

So, eliminate the first line which reads `int i = 0,j = 0,t = 0;`. Declare loop counters inline:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

And declare your temp variable in the place where its used:

```
                Console.WriteLine("c[{0}]={1}, c[{2}]={3}", i, c[i], j, c[j]);
                int t=c[i];
                c[i]=c[j];
                c[j]=t;
```

**Eliminate hard-coded array bounds.**

This:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
```

Becomes this:

```
for(i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most people would not bother making a *bubble sort* elegant. In *general*, though, I find that doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
    Item item = items[i];
    // do something with item
}
```

is both more elegant and more maintainable than doing this:

```
Item item;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    // do something with item
}
```

In other words, **declare your variables within the smallest applicable scope**. Otherwise you might find yourself doing something with `i` or `item` at some other point in the code and then using them again where you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

- I would use a swap methed to swap the two array items.
  (details of how to write swap method left as homework!)
- You should think about the case when the items are already in order
- You should read up on Insertion sort for more marks :-)
- Rather then reading the test data from the keyboard, see if you can learn how to use nUnit

Comment: Ian, I voted this up because your point about the swap method is valid. Just FYI though, someone added the homework tag, but I asked this to make a point at work.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer this:

```
string foo [] = new string[] {"abc", "def", "aaa", "feaf", "afea" };
Array.Sort(foo);
```

But that's just me. Sort is a solved problem, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: That wasn't there when I wrote this answer. But yeah, it's prolly homework.

Comment: And, this is actually wrong. If you look at the MS documentation, Array.Sort uses a QuickSort not a BubbleSort :)

Comment: It does matter when the question is specifically asking about *bubble* sort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an improvement in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595310/674700) proposed by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). After each loop, the number of iterations should exclude the last item processed in the previous iteration. So, here's the code:

```
public void BubbleSortImproved<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    BubbleSortImproved<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default);
}

public void BubbleSortImproved<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    bool stillGoing = true;
    int k = 0;
    while (stillGoing)
    {
        stillGoing = false;
        //reduce the iterations number after each loop
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1 - k; i++)
        {
            T x = list[i];
            T y = list[i + 1];
            if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
            {
                list[i] = y;
                list[i + 1] = x;
                stillGoing = true;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = {4,5,7,1,8};           

int n1, n2;
bool stillgoing = true;

while (stillgoing)
{
    stillgoing = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < (array.Length-1); i++)
    {                  
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
        {
            n1 = array[i + 1];
            n2 = array[i];

            array[i] = n1;
            array[i + 1] = n2;
            stillgoing = true; 
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

Took some ideas from Jon skeet...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public int[] BubbleSortInAesc(int[] input)
    {
        for (int i = input.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)
            {
                if (input[j] > input[j + 1])
                {
                    //Swap the numbers
                    input[j] = input[j + 1]+input[j];
                    input[j + 1] = input[j] - input[j + 1];
                    input[j] = input[j] - input[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm in ok, but I would put the sort functionality in a seperate class and method.