# Bubble Sorting not Giving Correct Result Code Attached C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

My sorting code not giving correct result it is not sortint the given list properly while i am not getting the error please check it,

```
  static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            List<int> a = new List<int>(new int[] { 3, 7, 6, 1, 8, 5 });

            int temp;

// foreach(int i in a)

for(int i=1; i<=a.Count; i++)

for(int j=0; j<a.Count-i; j++)

if (a[j] > a[j + 1])

{

temp = a[j];

a[j] = a[j + 1];

a[j + 1] = temp;

Console.WriteLine(a[j]);


}

Console.Read();

}
```

Comment: this is not code review site. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: dont try to write code that has been written milion of times already if you are not expierenced .... use existing imlementation, look on google
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort#C.23

Comment: Your code *does* correctly sort the input. But the `Console.WriteLine` calls are unrelated to that.

Comment: @Damain i have to write the output of the code

Comment: If you're still looking at this - observe that if the array is already sorted, no swaps will take place. But your `Console.WriteLine` call is inside the block where swaps take place. So you'll get no output if the array is already sorted. Instead, have a separate loop after your current ones, to loop through the array and do `Console.WriteLine` on each element.

Answer (score 2):

i could not understand your code and i do not know C#. But anyways, here is the sorting logic for bubble sort (written in c).

```
//assuming there are n elements in the array a[]

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   for(j=1; j<n-i; j++)
        {   if(a[j] < a[j-1])
            {   temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

and you can also refer to:
[www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort)

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is not a implementation of the [Bubble Sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You forgot to loop while no number is swapped anymore. Here is a Bubble Sort implementation written [by John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595310/637967). The `stillGoing` check is what at least is missing in your implementation:

```
public void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list);
{
    BubbleSort<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default);
}

public void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    bool stillGoing = true;
    while (stillGoing)
    {
        stillGoing = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length-1; i++)
        {
            T x = list[i];
            T y = list[i + 1];
            if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
            {
                list[i] = y;
                list[i + 1] = x;
                stillGoing = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the console.write from the nested loops. place console.write outside the nested loops in a new for loop or foreach.
then you will get the correct order. otherwise, the logic of bubble sort is correct