# Logic behind a bubble sort

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

I am doing a bubble sort exercise and my feeling is that it is very close to correct.
As it is at the moment I am presented with an eternal loop.

Where does the fault lie ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 2, 4, 8, 5, 88, 55, 32, 55, 47, 8, 99, 120, 4, 32 };
        int temporary;
        bool sorted;
        do
        {
            sorted = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int a = numbers[i];
                int b = numbers[i + 1];
                if (a > b)
                {
                    temporary = a;
                    a = b;
                    b = temporary;

                    sorted = true;

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("sorted");
        } while (sorted == true);


        foreach (int i in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Killercam I think that the question states this is a race condition.

Comment: Cool. Apologies to all... :'[

Comment: Your loop ALLWAYS runs with each iteration 1 to many times (and that stack). With each iteration you need to decrease end condition by 1. So you should write variable (that have numbers.length) and in condition write i< 'variable'--. Also, you arent SAVING results in array

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the most elegant way to bubble-sort in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595244/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-bubble-sort-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach in C# is to use a generic bubble sort

```
public void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> list);
{
    BubbleSort<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default);
}

public void BubbleSortImproved<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    bool stillGoing = true;
    int k = 0;
    while (stillGoing)
    {
        stillGoing = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1 - k; i++)
        {
            T x = list[i];
            T y = list[i + 1];
            if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0)
            {
                list[i] = y;
                list[i + 1] = x;
                stillGoing = true;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

A brief explanation of this algorithm is given by Jon Skeet in his [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595310/626442). "It uses an arbitrary comparer, but lets you omit it in which case the default comparer is used for the relevant type. It will sort any (non-readonly) implementation of IList, which includes arrays."

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for generics, BUT! algoritham is wasting time going over 'end' objects that are allready sorted. Bubble is called 'bubble' coz he pushes allways biggest number to most right end. So no need to check it over and over for every iteration. Store 'Length' into variable, and -- it in the condition.

Comment: Please check [this improved version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742136/674700) of [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You exchange `a` with `b` but you DON'T do anything to your input array. Thus, you are constantly exchanging values in memory but the original array is not changed. Try:

```
            for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++ )
            {
                if ( numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1] )
                {
                    temporary = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = temporary;

                    sorted = true;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not writing the results back onto the array.

Use this instead:

```
//temporary = a;
//a = b;
//b = temporary;

numbers[i] = b;
numbers[i + 1] = a;
```

Comment: And if I may add, check out the difference between a Value type and a Reference type.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
    {
            temporary = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
            numbers[i + 1] = temporary;

            sorted = true;

     }
```

changes made in `a`,`b` doesn't reflect in `numbers[i]` `numbers[i+1]` because a and b are mere `copy` of `numbers[i]` `numbers[i+1]`..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = { 2, 4, 8, 5, 88, 55, 32, 55, 47, 8, 99, 120, 4, 32 };
    int temporary;
    bool sorted;

    do
    {
        sorted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
            {

                temporary = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                numbers[i + 1] = temporary;

                sorted = true;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("sorted");
    } while (sorted == true);

    foreach (int i in numbers)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
}
```